# how to restructure kafka data on mongodb sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

i am using mongodb connector from the mongodb official page https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/tutorials/tutorial-setup/#std-label-kafka-tutorials-docker-setup i what the connector to to restructure the data in mongodb i have the example

```
{"_id": "19.12.2023", "build_chamber": {"temperature": 15.3}}
{"_id": "19.12.2023", "recoater": {"temperature": 15.3}}
{"_id": "19.12.2023", "build_chamber": {"humidity_absolut": 35.1}}
{"_id": "20.12.2023", "build_chamber": {"temperature": 17.1}}
```

this is the config that i use. but it didnt work

```
{
  "name": "mongo-sink",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "your_topic",
    "connection.uri": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "database": "your_database",
    "collection": "your_collection",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "document.id.strategy": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.PartialValueStrategy",
    "document.id.strategy.overwrite.existing": "true",
    "document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.type": "AllowList",
    "document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.list": "_id"
  }
}
```

this is the output that i want to be on monogdb

```
{
  "_id": "19.12.2023",
  "build_chamber": {"temperature": 15.3, "humidity_absolut": 35.1},
  "recoater": {"temperature": 15.3}
}
{
  "_id": "20.12.2023",
  "build_chamber": {"temperature": 17.1}
}
```